# 70-511 Exam Practice Calculator

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm studying to take exam 70-511 and in Chapter 1 a suggested practice is: Build a calculator program that uses the UniformGrid control for the number button layout and a toolbar for the function key layout, host both in a single grid.

I've added the following uniform grid, but how can I add the toolbar with the Enter, + and - buttons?

```
<UniformGrid Name="calculatorGrid" Rows="3" Columns="3">
        <Button Content="1" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="2" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="3" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="4" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="5" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="6" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="7" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="8" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="9" Margin="2" />
</UniformGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ToolBarTray Grid.Row="0" Background="White">
        <ToolBar Band="1" BandIndex="1">
            <Button Content="Enter" />
            <Button Content="Add" />
            <Button Content="Delete" />
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
    <UniformGrid Name="calculatorGrid" Grid.Row="1" Rows="3" Columns="3">
        <Button Content="1" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="2" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="3" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="4" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="5" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="6" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="7" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="8" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="9" Margin="2" />
    </UniformGrid>
</Grid>
```

Although you may want to provide images for the toolbar buttons.

Comment: Thanks, the book seems to be decent but some of these concepts are not very well covered in the book. Could you recommend a site that shows good examples of WPF layout controls?

Comment: Try searching for 'WPF layout'.  You'll find plenty of stuff.